# Exponentiation by cyclic shifting

Tags: algorithm, bit-shift, discrete-mathematics, exponentiation

Some other topic here on SO mentioned the paper “[Fast Exponentiation with Precomputation](http://www.ccrwest.org/gordon/fast.pdf)” by Brickell et al., which, along with simple concept of precomputation of powers corresponding to binary digits, had a statement about “exponentiation by cyclic shifting” (as far as I understood it). Unfortunately, that part of the paper was expressed in a very general form, so I simply can't figure out whether they were talking something obvious that becomes sophisticated with bases other than 2**n, or there really exist some method of exponentiation other than multiplication (squaring)?

For example, let's say we have `x = 5` (that's `00101` in binary). How is it possible to end up with `y = 5 * 5` (that's `11001` in binary), using only bit-shifting and perhaps some addition(s)? Of course, the algorithm should be more effective than multiplication, — the answer “you may emulate each multiplication by a bunch of bit-shifting and additions, as `y = (5 << 2) + (5 << 0)`” doesn't count. Well, it could count if sparse numbers were usual, but it's not a common scenario, and determining the exact bit-population count is also time-consuming, so, unless a number is *very* sparse, it's not worth trying, the more so that after each squaring a new assessment is needed.

Comment: The cyclic shift thing appears to be about math in GF(p**n) .. which I know nothing about, other than that it probably wouldn't apply to normal math.

Answer (score 1):

The method is called "exponentiation by binary decomposition" and you can find a discussion in Knuth 4.6.3. For example, [image: xcubed], thus in the first case you need 7 multiplications, but in the second 3 (note that `8 = 100` in binary). The code to do this is as follows:

```
long power( int x, int n ){
   long result = 1;
   long base = x;
   while( true ){
      if( n & 1 ) result = base * result;
      n = n >> 1;
      if( n == 0 ) return result;
      base = base * base;
   }
}
```

Comment: You are talking about the well-known “exponentiation by squaring”, which employs no bit-shifting. That `n >>= 1` operation is merely an “integer divide by 2” and is not absolutely necessary — you can achieve the same results by directly checking particular bit using a bit-mask, this would save you some CPU time, provided that `n` is also a big number.